# Show an App Update Dialog with various options and allow to set the prompt duration in Android

Tags: android, version, notify, app-update

I want to show a dialog to notify the user that the new version of an App is available on the play store.

My requirements are as below.

**1)** If the major version & minor version number of the VersoinName has changed, then the dialog should be shown with the force update option and it shows every time on the open of the App.

**2)** If the patch version number has changed, then the dialog should be shown with two buttons (Next Time & Update). And this dialog will be prompt on Each Day(means it should prompt once in a day) (Not every time).

**3)** If the revision number has changed, the dialog should be shown with three buttons(Update, Next Time & Skip). And this dialog will be prompt on Each Week(means it should prompt once in a week) (Not every time).

**Note:-** I have tried [Android App Update Dialog by Siren](https://github.com/eggheadgames/Siren) this library, but it does not fulfill all the above-mentioned requirements.

Please suggest workarounds.

Thank you.

Comment: You could store the latest version of the app on the server and then compare the version number. Also there's two ways to update the first you will update the version code and version number on the server or if user opens the app and it's version code is greater than that stored on server then update it by making a post request. Hope that helps.

Comment: @deepakkumar Thank you for the response, but my app has a backend in Firestore
And I have achieved what you have suggested via Remote-Config. but my concern is to show Dialog on the bases of Day and Week.

Comment: please ask a new question in detail, so that we can understand the problem in detail.